# Aggregate events on timestamp with Kafka Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, stream, apache-kafka-streams

I have two topics that contain some metrics events. Each metric is produced at a certain timestamp. I need to merge some metrics; the only common key is the timestamp.

I have created two `KStream` with a `TimestampExtractor` to extract metric timestamps.

I need to join those two streams to create a new event that contains all the metrics with the same timestamp but can't figure out how to use Kafka Stream to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Joins in Kafka Streams are key-based, so you would need to set the timestamps as record key. You can do this using `KStream#process(...)` (in older versions `KStream#transform(...)`) which allows you to access the timestamp (in older versions, you would need to use the `context` object from `init()` to access the timestamp).

After you have put the timestamp into the key, you can use a windowed kstream-kstream join to compute the final result.